# Why did total install of my app on Google Play decrease?

Tags: android, download, google-play, installation

Current install of my app is 32000.
Total install - 55000.

Normally when we search our app on Google Play, it will display: 50000-100000.

But since last night it became 10000 - 50000. I don't understand what happened. I checked in Google play console, and everything is good (55000).

Does any body have the same problem? What is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Same here!
Also installs decrease and low listing place is observed.
Looks like some crazy indian developer bug

Answer (score 0):

Same trouble!  Today I saw that number of downloads in my app decreased to 100. But yesterday was few thousands.

Comment: Problem was solved after reporting to Google. But yesterday it happened again. And now my number of downloads is till less than 50.000 (the real number is 65000).